# Grande parte do meu site virou um link

Tags: php, html, link

pessoal alguém sabe me dizer qual problema?
estava tentando fazer um site comum e fiz a pagina de login.php, porem quando coloquei o link no menu da index.php meu site todo virou um link.
Agora todo lugar que eu aperto e varias frases estão aparecendo como um link indo direto para a pagina de login não entendi porque isso, ja aconteceu com alguem?

```
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>

    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href=""> Anuncios</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login</li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

esta é a parte do menu

Comment: Talvez seja porque o seu último link no menu não possui `</a>`

Comment: gente parece que sei la sem querer criei tipo sistema de qualquer coisa que a pessoa clica ela tem que logar tipo isso, é assim mesmo ou sera algum erro?

Answer (score 6):

Você deve corrigir esse trecho:

```
<li><a href="login.php">Login</li>
```

Para isso:

```
<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
```

Provavelmente, a falta de fechamento da tag `</a>` é que causou a confusão.

Comment: Obg faltou esta atenção mesmo que nem reparei